# Angular Unknown provider error: what's the meaning of the chain of functions, mentioned in error message?

Tags: angularjs

I get an error from Angular:

```
angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: utilProvider <- util <- AuthInterceptor <- $http <- $templateFactory <- $view <- $state
```

I'm trying to localize the error, but I don't understand the meaning of chain of functions that the error message mensions:

```
utilProvider <- util <- AuthInterceptor <- $http <- $templateFactory <- $view <- $state
```

Can you explain, what are these guys? What's the order of them? It looks like a dependency stack, but is it right-to-left or left-to-right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error stack is to be read Left to Right.

It doesn't necessarily mean error is in the first object, it rather means error occured when trying to use that first object.

Angular generated error stack offers link to previous error, and you can trace your bug to its origin.

If you are developing in Chrome, the link is clickable in console and leads to Angular website where you can see some description of the error and most common causes.

Comment: Yep, I clicked the link and read the description of error, but it's too general. So, what's the relation of chain memebers? Does `a -> b` mean that `a` requires `b` as its dependency in configuration block? So angular started from `$state`, required `$view`, ... , required `util` and `util` failed to find `utilProvider`?

Comment: It means B tried to instantiate A and failed doing that.

Comment: Ah, so they "right" members are looking for definitions of "left" members and trying to create them? Thanks!